# Use the value inside a cell as variable for a function

Tags: excel, variables, excel-formula

I would like to create a dynamic function in excel (no VBA) to pass the value of a variable to a number of similar functions. Example:
instead of doing:
=sum(a1:z1)
=sum(a2:z2)
=sum(a3:z3)
and then rewrite all functions to do:
=sum(a1:t1)
=sum(a2:t2)
=sum(a3:t3)

I would like to do:
=sum(a1:"var"&1)
=sum(a2:"var"&2)
=sum(a3:"var"&3)
where I could define var=z the first time and var=t the second time.

do you know if it is possible?

thanks a lot for your help
rob

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with.
Whatever is in D3 is your "var" (put the letter of your column), the 6 is your hardcoded column (1, 2, 3, etc)

```
=SUM(A1:INDIRECT((CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("D3"),6))))
```

Comment: perfect, "INDIRECT" is exaclty what I was looking for!
it works
thanks a million